# Trying to stop setInterval loop on last item

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, cycle

I'm trying to use setInterval to cycle through a list changing classes as it goes until the last item. It is working but I've been unable to stop it from cycling. I'd also like to have the last item to end on a unique class.
This is what I've got so far.

```
<ul id="provision1" class="provisioning-list">
    <li class="in-progress">Configure Active Directory</li>
    <li>Create User Accounts and Groups</li>
    <li>Build Server Configurations</li>
    <li>Create NTFS</li>
    <li>Create Network</li>
    <li>Apply SDN Rules</li>
    <li class="last">Configure Users</li>
</ul>
```

Something like this

```
var toggleSlide = function(){

$("#provision1 li.in-progress").removeClass('in-progress').addClass('complete')
    .next().add("#provision1 li:first").last().addClass("in-progress");
}

setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var toggleSlide = function(){
    var current = $("#provision1 li.in-progress"),
        next = current.next();

    // stop if there is no next element or we reached the .last element
    if (current.is('.last') || next.length === 0){
       clearInterval( timer );
       return;
    }

    current.removeClass('in-progress');
    next.addClass('in-progress');
    },
    timer = setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
```

---

**Demo**

```js
var toggleSlide = function() {
        var current = $("#provision1 li.in-progress"),
          next = current.next();

        // stop if there is no next element or we reached the .last element
        if (current.is('.last') || next.length === 0) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          return;
        }

        current.removeClass('in-progress');
        next.addClass('in-progress');
      },
      timer = setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
```

```css
.in-progress{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="provision1" class="provisioning-list">
  <li class="in-progress">Configure Active Directory</li>
  <li>Create User Accounts and Groups</li>
  <li>Build Server Configurations</li>
  <li>Create NTFS</li>
  <li>Create Network</li>
  <li>Apply SDN Rules</li>
  <li class="last">Configure Users</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I ended up going with:  'var toggleSlide = function(){
    var current = $("#provision1 li.in-progress"),
        next = current.next();

    // stop if there is no next element or we reached the .last element
    if (current.is('.last') || next.length === 0){
       clearInterval( timer );
       $('.last').removeClass('in-progress').addClass('error');
       return;
    }

    current.removeClass('in-progress').addClass('complete');
    next.addClass('in-progress');
    },
    timer = setInterval(toggleSlide, 2400);'

Comment: @JasonFernald that is fine. I just wanted to showcase the flow. You can do whatever suits your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

To stop a `setInterval();` you can use `clearInterval();` like so:

```
var intv = setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
clearInterval(intv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change JS with following

```
var toggleSlide = function(){
    var $cur_element = $("#provision1 li.in-progress");
    $cur_element.removeClass('in-progress')
  .addClass('complete');
  if($cur_element.hasClass("last")) {
    clearInterval(interval_var);
  } else {
    $cur_element.next().add("#provision1 li:first")
    .last().addClass("in-progress");
  }
}

var interval_var = setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1144zkkg/)

Comment: another simple solution. Thanks everyone